# OutOfMemory on Pentaho due to unreleased transformations

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

we are using pentaho 9.1 on java 8 which is currently configured to use 4GB of memory (for both xmx and xms). In some complex jobs we have OutOfMemory issue. After analyzing the dump it looks like there are several transformations kept in memory even if related job is finished which are not released by JVM.

Is there anyone who had similar issue ? If so, what kind of fix did you do ?

Comment: you are keeping xmx and xms same, technically it is not advisable. Keep XMS half od what you are assigning to XMX and check. also which environment you are using ? how do you execute jobs? using kitchen utility ?

Comment: Jobs are executed via CURL command.